# Event not fired when removing value from autocomplete dropdown

Tags: primefaces

I'm upgrading Primefaces from 10 to 11. When deleting a value from a dropdown the change event is not fired. So the previous dropdown value is still selected. I have found that setting `forceSelection = "false"` in autocomplete the change event fires correctly when removing a value from the dropdown. Setting `forceSelection = "true"` it does not fire at all when removing a value from the dropdown. The change event should fire when the component loses focus, like when you click somewhere else on the page. When writing something the the dropdown like "test" and removing the value letter by letter with backspace, the event is fiering correctly for all but the last letter. If selecting the whole value and deleting the event is not fired.

Comment: Please create an issue https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/new/choose

Comment: I believe your issue is this one: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/8717 which is fixed for 12.0.0 can you try 12.0.0-SNAPSHOT and see if its fixed?